# C# - WPF - Updating the UI from another class on another Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, dispatcher

I have looked around the internet and found a nice solution which I am incorporating into my code below however it doesn't quite do exactly what I want, it works when just calling an update but I want to run a method in another class then let that method call the method that will report back to the UI and just pass some information so this mock up is just changing the button content before the operation is ran.

Using a Dispatcher I can get a UI control to update however I don't just wish to do that I want to perform some functions then have the UI Update.
So there maybe some theory I am not getting, I know the Invoke is a synchronous operation and breaking through the code it does run but the UI doesn't update.

**MainWindow**
Has a single button with content "CLICK ME"

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static Button windowButton;
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            windowButton = btnStart;
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Run a Process in another class on a different Thread
            ProcessClass processClass = new ProcessClass();
            Task processTask = new Task(() =>
            {
                processClass.DoSomething();
            });
            processTask.Start();
            
        }
    }
}
```

**ProcessClass**

```
class ProcessClass:MainWindow
    {
        
        public static void UpdateUI()
        {
            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
            {
                windowButton.Content = "CHANGED CONTENT";
            });
        }
        
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            UpdateUI();
            int counter = 0;
            for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                counter += i;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            MessageBox.Show($"Task Completed, answer is {counter}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that ProcessClass is your own code that you can update, change the signiture of `DoDomething()` to

```
public async Task DoSomething(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    progress.Report("Begin DoSomething()");

    var counter = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        counter += i;
        await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);

        progress.Report($"DoSomething() - i = {i}");
    }

    progress.Report($"DoSomething() Completed, answer is {counter}");
}
```

Now your button click handler can be written

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // usually you would update some other control such as a TextBlock
     // for the feedback, rather than the button content
     var progress = new Progress<string>(s => btnStart.Content = s);
     ProcessClass processClass = new ProcessClass();
     await processClass.DoSomething(progress).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot I have been trying to figure this out for a few days :) I just need to understand it now. Thanks again.

Comment: @C-Sharpie for more info on async / await, check out Stephen Cleary's blog https://blog.stephencleary.com/

Comment: Thanks again. I will give this a look tomorrow. I am having 1 issue with the above solution, although it works a treat it seems to be locking the UI while processing the DoSomething. Is this right or is there something I can do to fix it?

Comment: @C-Sharpie I've updated the code - I forgot to add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to each await call

Comment: The changed cause an error at runtime. It seems to hang for a few seconds then it says: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.'

Comment: With regard to my previous comment, do all my methods need to be async? so methods inside the DoSomething? I have a lot of methods and I have methods in other methods ran from the DoSomething. Do they all need to be async? Are these not running on a separate thread from the call button? I managed to get a simple example working using async and an example with the UI locking using a void method inside the DoSomething. I need to do a lot of reading up.

Comment: A method only needs to be async if you're going to await a task within it. Async / await has nothing to do with threads - https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: thanks again, i've figured it out and got it to work exactly as I need and i've understood it through the MS DOCs. Really happy about this, thanks for helping and pointing me in the right direction, you're a legend :)